Manga where a girl is reincarnated and drafted into a war
It about a girl who was reincarnated into a world that’s in the middle of a war and she was drafted into it, she also has healing magic and has to serve a reckless general.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Its Genderswapped Medic's Battlefield Diary

girl - check
middle of war - check
healing magic - check
reckless superior (not general) - check


After her aptitude for healing magic was discovered, she decided to
volunteer in the army as a second-class medic, all to raise money for
the orphanage where she was born and raised. However, without even
getting magic training, she is attached to an assault squad,
repeatedly fighting on the most cruel battlefields on the Western
Front.
The mission given to her was to become the personal medic of the
frontline’s ace, Garback, and not let him die at any cost. But he
turned out to be the worst commander, who will try to get results
whatever the cost, even if it means the death of his subordinates!

